# Nativescript Screen overlay detected error

Tags: typescript, android-permissions, nativescript

When trying to load nativescript-imagepicker on android 6.0.1 After requesting permission for using the following code

```
 public pick(){
        var context = imagePicker.create({
            mode: 'single'
        });

        if (platformModule.device.os === "Android" && platformModule.device.sdkVersion >= 23)  {   
            permissions.requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, "I need these permissions to read from storage")
            .then(function() {
                console.log("Permissions granted!");
                startSelection(context);
            })
            .catch(function() {
                console.log("Uh oh, no permissions - plan B time!");
            });
            } else {
                startSelection(context);
            }   

        }

}
```

I received the message "Screen overlay detected To change this permission setting, you first have to turn off the screen overlay from Settings > Apps"

upon clicking open settings the application that I am working on is visible but cannot be selected.

I have these settings in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

How does on fix this. I have used the plugin before on an older version of android without encountering this error however I do not have access to that code to test it anymore.

Deleting and reinstalling the app now allows it to be selected on the menu however I have no clue what to do from there. I can't find an accept button or anything of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. There was a one note badge up that I had to get rid of in order to proceed.

Comment: Hi, could you show more details about what causes this problem and how to solve it? thank you

Comment: This is an old post. At the time though android had just introduced badges at the OS level. Badges are little circular screen overlays. The app started to malfunction because the OneNote app had a badge on the screen. You can try making sure there are no badges up.